# Experience to qualify for PMP certification

Tags: project-team, certification, business-improvement

I have not led a project of an industry, but I have an experience in Business Management whereby I have led a group of employees.

Can I still enroll for PMP certification?

Comment: Was anything in your job a "project"? Did you handle, say, the construction, staffing and opening of a new franchise lot? Or was it "just" the day to day work that happens?

Comment: Only PMI can answer this. If we say "yes" and PMI says "no", the answer is "no".

Comment: This one we can answer without contacting PMI, so i think it's worth to be opened because others might face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In PMI's website we can read the [Official PMP Guide](https://www.pmi.org/official-pmp-guide).

In that Official PMP Guide we can know the experience to qualify

> - 4-year degree, 3 years of experience leading projects, AND 35 hours project management education/training
>
> — OR —
>
> - High school diploma, associate's degree or the global equivalent, 5 years of experience leading projects, AND 35 hours project management
>     education/training

You need to be able to justify / prove / validate one or the other so that you can apply.